# Creating a php/mysql Delete form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-delete

When a was creating a little code in php/mysql I wanted to know how to build a php form to delete an item from database.

The first code is index.php the goal of the script is to gather information about the visitor's of my website because users who want to deface my website.

```
<?php

    $getting_ips = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_capture_module");
    if ($getting_ips) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getting_ips)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><strong><? echo $row['country']; ?></strong></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['browser']; ?></td>

        <td><a href="http://<?php echo $row['ipaddr']; ?>"><?php echo $row['ipaddr']; ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['method']; ?></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $row['sploit'];  ?></strong></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="delete.php">delete</a></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
// The Second Code is capture.php
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
        ....
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip_capture_module(country,browser,ipaddr,method,date) VALUES(
            '$country_name',
            '$browser',
            '$ip',
            '$method',
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())") or die ("<br>Error in inserting in IP: ".mysql_error()."<br>");
```

Comment: do you have some code that you have already written for this application?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You have to be **much more specific** then that. What parts are you having problems with? Edit your question and post your current code so that we can see your effort.

Comment: You might want to start here: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php Once you have tried a few things, try posting what you have so we can give more specific direction

Comment: Yes Maximus i hade it :P i rewrite the POst i need the Delete.php code xD

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
//INSERT CODE HERE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE
//DO MORE ERROR CHECKING NECESSARY
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE row='value' LIMIT 1");
//OR YOU CAN USE MYSQLI
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE row='value' LIMIT 1");
mysql_close(); 
//MYSQLI AGAIN
mysqli_close();

exit();
}
```

I can't give you anymore since your question was so broad. Try using PHP.NET for more info.

Comment: Thank's to all , Im soo bad in english , i have the fresh prononsation , i will rewrite the post to clear the idea of the problem , i have a feeling that all friend's here want to help me , and im great and happy to be here

Answer (score 0):

```
  DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `some_row`='row_value'
```

This is the best i can do, since you haven't given enought informations to help you more

Comment: THank's alot ahmad albayati i will see what i do with your solution , and thank's again =)